# In what situations would Rank and Dense Rank be useful?

Tags: sql-server

I know the syntax for using the Rank and Dense Rank functions
but I can't find any uses in the real world for this .

For example **DENSE_RANK**

```
ranking       userid
1               500
1               500
2               502
2               502
```

and **Rank**

```
Ranking UserID
    1   500
    1   500
    1   500
    1   500
    1   500
    1   500
    1   500
    8   502
    8   502
    8   502
    8   502
    8   502
    8   502
    8   502
    15  504
```

I can't understand how the 1,1 2,2 values would be useful in the real world.
On the other hand, I **do** understand very clearly what the real-world uses for `row_number over partition` are; I just can't find what can I do with this kind of information (dense & regular rank)

Comment: marc_s : you right i will remove ,  it was in my head since ive accomplished these functions without using the ready ones in 2008.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6681841/27535

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use it to find the top n rows for each group

There is a very good explanation here:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2920665938600

Answer (score 3):

Specific examples would be arbitrary and not necessarily helpful. So long as you understand what they do (q.v. @Kevin Burton's link), and can remember at least vaguely that this functionality exists, then if or when a situation comes up where they would be useful--if not critical--you'll be able to pull them out of the database developer's bag of tricks. (I've used RANK once, maybe twice, and it was very useful each time, but I can't--and don't need to--recall the details without looking them up.)

Comment: That applies to pretty much every one of those OLAP features, such as `CUBE`, `ROLLUP`, `CONNECT BY`, etc...

Comment: Yep--and it just feels great to drag out some ridiculous obscure function to convert 30 lines of query and subquery into 6 of a single query.

Comment: Yes, and be the only one that can still decipher its meaning - or extend it :)

Comment: Nah, obscure functions are well documented in BOL. Obscure code and/or logic, now, that's where your job security is.  :)